# Which activation function to use for sequence prediction in a lstm network in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I have built a network to predict 4 time series simultaneously, say [respiration, blood-pressure, pulse, spo2], using TimeDistributed layer in Keras. Before feeding into the network I normalize the series using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` function. Here is a snapshot of original data and normalized data:

```
Original:                   Normalized:         
resp sysbp pulse spo2       resp    sysbp        pulse       spo2
18  111.5   71  97      -0.322154   -0.007753   -0.865683    0.051831
18  109.5   71  97      -0.322154   -0.067897   -0.865683    0.051831
19  122     70  97      -0.151163    0.308004   -0.922641    0.051831
18  128     72  98      -0.322154    0.488436   -0.808725    0.292901
18  125     71  96      -0.322154    0.39822    -0.865683   -0.189238
20  113     71  96       0.019828    0.037355   -0.865683   -0.189238
16  121     71  96      -0.664136    0.277932   -0.865683   -0.189238
20  119     71  97       0.019828    0.217788   -0.865683    0.051831
18  119    71.5 97      -0.322154    0.217788   -0.837204    0.051831
19  119     88  97      -0.151163    0.217788    0.102603    0.051831
16  119     88  97      -0.664136    0.217788    0.102603    0.051831
14  119     87  97      -1.006117    0.217788    0.045645    0.051831
19  119     88  98      -0.151163    0.217788    0.102603    0.292901
29  119     92  96       1.558744    0.217788    0.330435   -0.189238
```

The ranges before & after normalization respectively are as follows:
`resp=[0,99] & [-3.4,13.5], sysbp=[0,269] & [-3.3,4.7], pulse=[0,204] & [-4.9,6.7], spo2=[0,100] & [-23.3,0.77]`

I have structured the data in timesteps of length 200, mentioned batch size as 100 and the number of dimensions, as we have seen above, is 4. Hence, the structure of my neural network looks like:

```
batch_size=100
x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,200,4) , name='input')
mask = Masking(mask_value=0., name='input_masked')(x)
lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(4, name="lstm1", dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))(mask)
output1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(4, activation='relu'), name='output1')(lstm1)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=output1)
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, [y_train1, y_train2], batch_size=batch_size, epochs=500, verbose=1)
```

The network is trained with no errors and gives **accuracy of 85%**. Now but when I predict my test data using the trained network, the output ranges of the predicted data fields are positive. Thus, after inverse scaling, the higher values are predicted nicely, but the lower values are not predicted at all. The lowest it goes is till the mean of the variable.

To experiment, I even tried with PReLU activation function, and some of the predicted values were negative, but still it was hardly catching up with the lowest possible values. The questions I have are:

- Is the structure and approach of sequence prediction is correct or am
  I missing something?
- And, is there a better activation function which I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

With ReLU you should scale your values from 0 to 1 not just remove mean and deviation which is what you are doing.

[ReLu Activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#/media/File:Rectifier_and_softplus_functions.svg) - Ask yourself: What happends when you are using negative values with this activation function?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so in that case, should we always scale values between 0 to 1 to avoid this? Or is there another activation which takes care of negative values?

Comment: There are activation functions that work fine for values from -1 to 1, it all depends on which activation function you use.

Have a look at this link for  a good visualization of activation functions.

Did rescaling from 0 to 1 help your result?



[link](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a7f872a80b7223ca5bb7690497ab2239)